# How to create blocks like on twitch?

Tags: html, css

How to create a blocks like on [this link](http://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Counter-Strike%3A%20Global%20Offensive)?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
        window.onload = function(){

    var height = 0;
    var width = 0;
    var count_blocks = 0;
    width = window.innerWidth; 

    var h_right_block = document.getElementById('right_block').offsetHeight;
    var h_i_right_block = document.getElementById('i_right_block').offsetHeight;

    h_i_right_block += 20; 

    if(h_i_right_block > h_right_block){
        var w_Scroll = getScrollBarWidth();
        count_blocks = (width - 270 - w_Scroll) / 270;
    }else{
        count_blocks = (width - 270) / 270; 
    }
    count_blocks = Math.floor(count_blocks); 
    var diff_width_block = 250 / count_blocks;
    diff_width_block = Math.round(diff_width_block); 
    diff_width_block = 250 - diff_width_block;
    //diff_width_block = diff_width_block + "px";

    $( '.box' ).css( 'width', diff_width_block );
};
```

Comment: Inspect element and you'll get an idea how to do it ;)

Comment: Yep, but how can I create a responsive blocks which can change their size depend on the browser width?

Comment: I've tried to make this in JS. Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/kvehqL6s/

Comment: @madLokesh This script changes width of blocks in real time depend of size of windows, it supposed to, but its not working like twitch :/

Comment: @Vasiliy You may want to paste the code or the link of the code in your question. Wait let me edit it. Also what do you mean by blocks. You mean rectangle UI ? If that is the case, you may want to improve the quality of question as well.

Comment: I agree with @madLokesh, at least could you post a screen shot and highlight what you're after?

Comment: I made this fiddle some time ago for a very simillar question. simple and easy to understand: http://jsfiddle.net/5w9ms9u4/

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez I thought about it. I want to find another way, because this is not very good in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one: jsfiddle url : http://jsfiddle.net/Khumesh/qsbtfhx4/

CSS:
 .section {
            clear: both;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

```
    .col {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

        .col:first-child {
            margin-left: 0;
        }

    .group:before,
    .group:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
    }

    .group:after {
        clear: both;
    }

    .group {
        zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 */
    }


    .span_3_of_3 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .span_2_of_3 {
        width: 66.1%;
    }

    .span_1_of_3 {
        width: 32.2%;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .col {
            margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
        }

        .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="section group">
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
            This is column 1
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
            This is column 2
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
            This is column 3
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
            This is column 4
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
            This is column 5
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
            This is column 6
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
            This is column 7
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
            This is column 8
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
            This is column 9
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No, I need to do so that the blocks are stretched to a certain width like on Twitch. At Twitch 5 blocks max-width == 6 min-width. I want to avoid empty spaces: [link](http://u.to/FOfKCg) . Image should have a max and min width to be on the whole browser

Answer (score -2):

You can use the tag `div` in `HTML` or any of [HTML5 tags](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)
As for positioning the elements you should see [Float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) property in `CSS`

you can see more here [link](http://igtfy.com/?q=css%20float%20and%20align) ;)

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://www.w3fools.com/) after seeing that link. Also, if you're advising to use floats, you would also benefit from reading [this](http://designshack.net/articles/css/farewell-floats-the-future-of-css-layout/).